# How to select different Cards and return the selected Cards to the Parent with React and Hooks?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to select a group of cards and to group the **selected Cards** into 2 groups.

```
let playerList = ['Jason', 'Mike', 'Bruce', 'Josh', 'Rick', 'William']
const Cards = () => {
   const [selectedPlayer, setSelectedPlayer] = useState('')

   return (
      <div className={styles.container}>
        <Grid container spacing={2} justify="center">
            {/* returns a PlayerCard for each element of the array */}
            {playerList.map((value, index) => {
                return <PlayerCard key={index} onClick={value => setSelectedPlayer(value)} playerName={value} />
            })}
        </Grid>
        {selectedPlayer}
      </div>
   )
}
```

I got it working to return the selectedPlayerName from the Child component to the Parent, but I don't know how I could store information in an array in this way.

The array should look like this if we select 4 players: `['Jason', 'Mike', 'Josh', 'Rick']` so i could randomly pick the players for each group.

So how can I make an **array to store these players** in when I select a Card?

How the Cards look like (you can select a Card with a mouse click):

[Player Cards](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4vVu.png)

Comment: It's worth creating a codesandbox of this so helpers can amend the code for you and provide an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to declare an array in react hooks like this

```
const [selectedPlayer, setSelectedPlayer] = useState([])
```

after that, you have to set the value in the selectedPlayer like this

```
{playerList.map((value, index) => {
                return <PlayerCard key={index} onClick={value => setSelectedPlayer([...selectedPlayer, value])} playerName={value} />
            })}
```

It will be working fine